# OpenCV detect lines of an 2d object exported as a jpg from SolidWorks

Tags: python, opencv

I have made a parallelepiped in SW and exported one of the faces as a jpg file. Now I am trying to detect the lines of the face and generate points on them.

[image]

My code detects the outer line of the img and puts some random points.

[image]

This is the code that i have, where face1.jpg is the initial photo.

```
img_copy = cv.imread('face1.jpg')
gray = cv.cvtColor(img_copy, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray_invert = cv.bitwise_not(gray)

contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(gray_invert,  cv.RETR_CCOMP, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
print("Numar de conture: {}\n".format(len(contours)))

cv.drawContours(img_copy, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)

cv.imshow('image', img_copy)
cv.waitKey(0)
```

Also based on one of the comments I've done the threshold and morphology. And I get two contours. One which is the hole img and one that is a point on the left corner of the object.

```
img = cv.imread('face1.jpg')
gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# cleaning img
ret, threshold = cv.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY + cv.THRESH_OTSU)
print(threshold)
kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)
opening = cv.morphologyEx(gray, cv.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(gray,  cv.RETR_CCOMP, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

cv.drawContours(img_copy, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)

cv.imshow('image', img_copy)
cv.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Do you want four points corners w/out rectangle?

Comment: Can you get rid of white edge around corner? Here is link https://ibb.co/SfGgDhW I can merely see white edge around rectangle image

Comment: I can't process the image beforehand. The idea is to save it from SW and do everything from py. I want points not only on corners but in lines too. This is a basic example that i want to try first. I want to be able to generate point also on more complex images. with circles or what not.

Comment: Threshold on the gray box. Use morphology to clean up (remove) small spots. Then get contours.  Then use the points of the contours.

Comment: @fmw42 I've done what you are saying and now i am getting only one contour and that is for the whole image. I'll update the post with the code that i've tried.

Comment: After thresholding is your box black or white?  If not white, then invert the image. Then get rid of any white spots using morphology before getting the external contour. Use cv2.inRange() to threshold on the gray box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use cv2.inRange() to threshold on the gray box in Python/OpenCV or otsu thresholding, but get the external contour.  Invert the image if the box is black on a white background.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('box.jpg')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

ret, threshold = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
threshold = 255 - threshold

# OR use inRange()
#lower=(70,60,60)
#upper=(90,80,80)
#threshold = cv2.inRange(img, lower, upper)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(threshold,  cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

cv2.imwrite('box_contour.jpg', img_copy)

img_copy=img.copy()
cv2.drawContours(img_copy, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)

cv2.imshow('threshold', threshold)
cv2.imshow('image', img_copy)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image]